# Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc, parameters

Trying to execute a stored procedure using JDBC, I can't seem to get past this error,

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter

```
public static void SP1() throws SQLException, IOException {

    try {

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp1;");

        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE PROCEDURE sp1(OUT cName VARCHAR(20))"
                + "SELECT CuratorName FROM curator "
                + "WHERE CuratorPhone = \"90394857\" INTO cName;");

        conn.commit();

        System.out.println("Sp1 created");

        CallableStatement cs3 = conn.prepareCall("{call sp1(?)}");
        cs3.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        cs3.execute();
        String result = cs3.getString("cName");
        System.out.println("Result from sp1:" + result);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the sproc run standalone (ie outside the Java)?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mysql running on localhost. I run everything in Netbeans IDE

Comment: Odd, I could not reproduce this exception.  Your code ran for me. I'm using MySQL version 5.5.22, MySQL connector JAR version 5.1.18, Windows 8.1 x64, Java 1.8.0_05, if any of that helps.

Answer (score -2):

If your Stored Procedure definition contains an IN parameter looking at the code you have shared, then the Call statement should look like this

```
 CallableStatement cs3 = conn.prepareCall("{call sp1(?)}");
    cs3.setString(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

The parameter needs to be set as an IN Parameter.

If your Stored Procedure definition contains an OUT Parameter then your call statement needs to be modified.

```
CallableStatement cs3 = conn.prepareCall("{? = call sp1()}");
        cs3.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

In any case, share your procedure definition, that would make it clearer.

Comment: I have tried your second option, as I have one out parameter. I now get this error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: `cs3.setString(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);` would be a syntax error as you are assigning an integer to a string parameter. You would assign a string value to it. And as this question is about `OUT`, it doesn't make sense as part of your answer. Secondly, the `{? = call sp1()}` escape would be for stored procedures with a single **return** value, not for `OUT` parameters.